# How to access fields from interface implementation for testing

Tags: java, testing, interface

I have an interface with a few methods

```
public interface Turret {

    void firePrimary();

    void fireSecondary();

    void reloadPrimary();

    .......
}
```

I have implementation of it which has protected fields. In my implementation of the above methods I change the values of the protected fields.

```
@Override
public void firePrimary() {
    if(shootablePriAmmo > 0) {
        shootablePriAmmo--; //Shootable ammo is a protected field inside the implementation
    }else{
        reloadPrimary();
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to test the fire primary method and check whether the `shootablePriAmmo` value was changed or not but since this is an interface implementation I cannot access the fields with interface methods and I don't want to write methods in interface for giving access to these fields as those methods won't be used anywhere else except for testing. If I write unit tests only on the implementation classes then I have to create public getters for these fields which I don't see is the correct way of doing it. What exactly should I do to overcome this? Am I violating any OOP principle?

**EDIT**
Here is the constructor of the implementation

```
public BasicTurret(int maxPriAmmo, int maxSecAmmo, int priAmmoCap, int secAmmoCap) {
    this.maxPriAmmo = maxPriAmmo;
    this.maxSecAmmo = maxSecAmmo;
    this.curPriAmmo = priAmmoCap;
    this.curSecAmmo = secAmmoCap;
    this.priAmmoCap = priAmmoCap;
    this.secAmmoCap = secAmmoCap;
    this.shootablePriAmmo = priAmmoCap;
    this.shootableSecAmmo = secAmmoCap;
}
```

Comment: Can you please make a flag for the same ?

Comment: @suresh I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce ammo holder interface to encapsulate ammo manipulations and simplify testing

```
interface AmmoHolder {
    getMax();
    get/setCur(); // consume or reload
    getShootable();
    getCap();
}

class BasicTurret(AmmoHolder primary, AmmoHolder secondary) {
    this.primaryAmmo = primary;
    this.secondaryAmmo = secondary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Hey just wanted to ask one thing, is it necessary to use interface or can I do it with a concrete class. At the moment I am using concrete class as I will just be having one implementation of AmmoHolder and also going by real life example a ammoholder is like an object than a service.

Comment: Of course you can use concrete class. I prefer to use interfaces just to keep domain model clear. But its your program, so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: "Keep domain model clear" sounds interesting. If you ever get time, do link me some source so that I can read a bit more about it. Added if you know any such source. :)

Comment: E.g. http file storage [public api](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chfs-api) (model description) and [runtime](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chfs-runtime) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object that holds the state for your values that change from these methods. Then pass a mock in through a constructor.

Comment: That's a good plan but I have fields which I don't pass in through the constructor. So I cannot keep the track of them.

Comment: How are they set now?  Inside the Default constructor? Setters?

Comment: Edited and added the constructor.

Comment: Your solution was correct but because there was no added code I got a bit confused. I am upvoting it but won't accept it.

Comment: Hey, np and thanks. I really should stop answering from my phone, I don't like writing code from it.  I'm glad you got your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unit-tests are normally created for an implementation, not for an interface, so in your unit-test you need to instantiate a class you want to test as a reference to an implementation, not an interface (in your case - BasicTurret). Also unit-tests are usually placed to the same package as the original class, so they have access to protected fields/methods if necessary.

```
BasicTurret turret = new BasicTurret(.., .., 5, ..);
turret.firePrimary();
assertEquals(4, turret.shootablePriAmmo);
```